# Form hook not found through module_hook_info in module subdirectory

Tags: 7

**Context:**
In my Drupal 7 project, I have a module with several submodules. Because the module's root directory got crowded, I moved the submodule files to their own directories within the root.

My module's structure is like this:

```
mymodule
├── mymodule.info
├── mymodule.module
├── mymodule1
│   ├── mymodule1.block.inc
│   ├── mymodule1.form.inc
│   ├── mymodule1.info
│   ├── mymodule1.module
│   ├── mymodule1.page.inc
│   └── pages
│       └── foo.tpl.php
└── mymodule2
    ├── classes
    │   └── foo
    │       └── Bar.php
    ├── mymodule2.form.inc
    ├── mymodule2.info
    ├── mymodule2.install
    ├── mymodule2.module
    ├── mymodule2.page.inc
    └── pages
        ├── foo.tpl.php
        └── bar.tpl.php
```

Before "the big move", files that are now in the subdirectories `mymodule1` and `mymodule2`, were located in their parent directory (the module's root directory).

---

**The problem:**
Ever since moving the files, my custom forms are not loading anymore. I have a form in `mymodule1.form.inc`, which used to load and render perfectly before. Now, when I use `drupal_get_form()` to load the form, I only get an empty form with a hidden build ID input.

Keep in the mind that the only thing that has changed here, is that the .inc files have been moved to the subdirectory, along with the module file. Also, `drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule1')` returns the correct path to the module in the subdirectory.

Strangely, there are also block hooks, located in `mymodule1.block.inc`, which work perfectly fine, even after clearing all caches.

This is the first time I'm working with separate directories per submodule within a module. I got the inspiration from the module `i18n`, which uses the same construction. I searched in the Drupal documentation and the code of `i18n`, but could not find where I'm going wrong.

Does anyone know where I could possibly have gone wrong, or if I need to add data to `mymodule1.module` or `mymodule1.info` to make this work? Thank you.

---

**Some details:**
Caches were cleared through `<path to project>/admin_menu/flush-cache` multiple times.

I use `module1_hook_info()` to direct the hooks for blocks and forms to separate files. This is the return value:

```
array (size=9)
  'block_info' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'block' (length=5)
  'block_configure' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'block' (length=5)
  'block_save' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'block' (length=5)
  'block_view' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'block' (length=5)
  'forms' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'form' (length=4)
  'form' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'form' (length=4)
  'form_validate' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'form' (length=4)
  'form_submit' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'form' (length=4)
  'form_alter' => 
    array (size=1)
      'group' => string 'form' (length=4)
```

My form functions are called:

- `mymodule1_foobar_form`
- `mymodule1_foobar_form_validate`
- `mymodule1_foobar_form_submit`

Comment: Have you updated the code that includes `mymodule1.form.inc` to include the new path?

Comment: @Clive I'm not including this file anywhere, since it worked without include before (and I didn't see similar includes in other modules) in neither .module or .info. Do you mean a `require_once`, `module_load_include()`? I got the impression that `require_once` is bad practice.

Comment: I mean `module_load_include()` - I reckon your original code worked because of an unintended side effect, more details in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Clive I found [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7), which is used to load files when working with a form. I moved `hook_forms()` back to my main module's file and now load the mymodule1.form.inc through there, like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_forms().
 */
function mymodule1_forms($form_id, $args)
{
    module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule1', 'mymodule1.form');
    $forms = array();

    $forms['mymodule1_foo_form'] = array(
        'callback' => 'mymodule1_foo_form',
    );

    return $forms;
}
```

Now all my forms are loading correctly (again), over both `mymodule1` and `mymodule2`.

The one thing I'm not sure about, that whether this could have been achieved without redundantly declaring the form callbacks to their same-named form IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at what happened here, I might be wrong.

`hook_form()` isn't a normal hook, it's only invoked for modules that define node types (you haven't indicated any of yours do). It isn't invoked when you arbitrarily invoke `drupal_get_form()`. Same goes for `hook_form_validate()` and `hook_form_submit()`.

Some of the hooks in your `hook_hook_info()` implementation *are* called for all modules, though. e.g. `hook_forms()` and `hook_form_alter()`.

I would surmise that `mymodule` contained an implementation of `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_forms()`, which was coincidentally invoked on the same page(s) as the forms that you've now moved to `mymodule1` were displayed. Those hooks being invoked implicitly result in `mymodule.form.inc` being included, and the functions were available.

Now that you've moved the code into `mymodule1`, I'm guessing you haven't implemented either of the hooks that would have resulted in that coincidental behaviour. So Drupal now can't find your form function, and fails silently.

To fix, include the file manually:

```
module_include('inc', 'mymodule1', 'mymodule1.form');
```

Comment: `mymodule` contains no code other than a theme registry function. The form hooks have been always been part of `mymodule1`. Before moving the files, the form was displayed. I do have an identical hook_info in `mymodule2`, which also has its own forms (which are also not loading now).

Comment: I put `module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule1', 'mymodule1.form');` on top of `mymodule1.module` and cleared my cache. This made no difference for me.

Comment: Worth a shot I guess, I don't know the answer then. I do know that using `hook_hook_info()` won't work to auto-include `MODULE.form.inc`, though, as you can see from the explanation about `hook_form()`, so I guess the quirk is elsewhere

Comment: I've tried including the file through `module1.info` (using `files[]`), but this did not make any difference either.

Comment: It wouldn't - `files[]` is for autoloading classes